# Would std::scoped_lock prevent deadlocks if the same mutex we're passed in twice?

Tags: c++, concurrency, operating-system, mutex, deadlock

I have code that will run a in a single thread needs to obtain the lock on two different buckets of a hash table. The problem is that there is a possibility of the two buckets being the same bucket (and therefore the same mutex would be locked twice). Would scoped_lock prevent this? Or would it be a self deadlock?

I thought of ways to use lock_guard where I conditionally create the second lock guard but it would go out of scope when the if-statement ended.

Comment: You probably want a `recursive_mutex`

Comment: You might need https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex or change your design

Comment: If you run only one thread, you don't need a mutex or a lock.

Comment: If you run multiple threads with multiple locks (one on each bucket) then you have a design that can deadlock.  In that case a thread must atomically grab all the locks it needs (or none). If threads can start locking buckets independently and you have threads that need the same buckets but lock them in different order you have a deadlock. So probably you are better of having one lock (and maybe a locked flag per bucket).